# Apply function recursively across 2 lists in Common Lisp

Tags: list, function, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I have a function written in common LISP that multiplies the first term of 2 polynomials which works exactly as I want it to (using other functions that I have written):

```
(defun firsttermmultiply (p1 p2)
    (let ((t1p1(car p1))
          (t1p2(car p2))
          (rem1(cdr p1))
          (rem2(cdr p2)))
        (cons (coeff t1p1 t1p2) (cutfront t1p1 t1p2)) 
    )
)
```

p1 and p2 are the polynomials and I want to recurse through both the lists so that I have one long list where all the terms from p1 and p2 have been applied to the line:

```
(cons (coeff t1p1 t1p2) (cutfront t1p1 t1p2))
```

I know that it requires the use of rem1 and rem2 as parameters for the separate recursive lines but I cannot get my head around the structure.

I have to do this functionally so I cannot use loop structures, only recursion.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output? It's not really clear right now what you're trying to do.  It may help to keep in mind that **mapcar** can accept multiple lists.  E.g., `(mapcar '+ '(1 2) '(3 4)) => (4 6)`.

Comment: I do not think that the code shown works as intended.  The tails of `p1` and `p2` are never used and do not appear in the result.

Answer (score 1):

is it one of those? Assuming those polys are of the same order.

```
(defun firsttermmultiply (p1 p2)
  (if (or (null p1) (null p2))
      nil
      (let ((t1p1(car p1))
            (t1p2(car p2))
            (rem1(cdr p1))
            (rem2(cdr p2)))

        (cons (coeff t1p1 t1p2) (firsttermmultiply rem1 rem2)))))


(defun firsttermmultiply (p1 p2)
  (if (or (null p1) (null p2))
      nil
      (let ((t1p1(car p1))
            (t1p2(car p2))
            (rem1(cdr p1))
            (rem2(cdr p2)))

        (cons (cons (coeff t1p1 t1p2) (cutfront t1p1 t1p2))
              (firsttermmultiply rem1 rem2)))))


(defun firsttermmultiply (p1 p2)
  (if (or (null p1) (null p2))
      nil
      (let ((t1p1(car p1))
            (t1p2(car p2))
            (rem1(cdr p1))
            (rem2(cdr p2)))

        (cons (coeff t1p1 t1p2)
              (cons (cutfront t1p1 t1p2)
                    (firsttermmultiply rem1 rem2))))))
```